# IE11 flexbox not accounting for height of wrapped text

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I know the end answer might be "IE sucks and you're S.O.L." but I can't figure out how to get this flex layout to work right in IE11 and was hoping someone here would understand why the layout was breaking/have some clever hack to fix it. In IE when the text wraps the border on the text collapses to just contain the first line.

The end goal is to have the text bottom aligned and have the svg fill the remaining space, but flexibly (I don't want to use a set height on the svg or text element) because this is for a web component I'm working on.

```css
div{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:#fafafa;
  border-radius:3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;   
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:stretch;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
h5{
  flex-shrink:1;
  text-align:center;
  margin:5px auto;
  max-width:100%;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
span{
  display:block;
  display:flex;
  align-self:stretch;
}
svg{
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 61.71 62.15"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:currentColor;}</style></defs><title>myThermometer</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_2-2" data-name="Layer 2"><path class="cls-1" d="M34,45.55V36.82a2.92,2.92,0,1,0-5.84,0v8.73a6.68,6.68,0,1,0,5.84,0Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M38.11,43.46V7a7,7,0,1,0-14,0V43.46a10.67,10.67,0,1,0,14,0ZM31.1,60a8.48,8.48,0,0,1-4.83-15.45v-3.2h1v-1h-1V37.72h1v-1h-1V34.11h2.06a4.08,4.08,0,0,1,1.07-.76v-.22H26.27V30.51H29.4v-1H26.27V26.91H29.4v-1H26.27V23.3H29.4v-1H26.27V19.7H29.4v-1H26.27V16.1H29.4v-1H26.27V12.49H29.4v-1H26.27V8.89H29.4v-1H26.27V7a4.83,4.83,0,1,1,9.66,0v37.5A8.48,8.48,0,0,1,31.1,60Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M49.34,44.75l-.91-1.31L50,43a.52.52,0,0,0,.37-.64A.53.53,0,0,0,49.7,42l-1.29.35.46-1.26a.53.53,0,0,0-.32-.67.52.52,0,0,0-.67.32L47.43,42l-.77-1.09a.52.52,0,0,0-.86.59l.92,1.32-1.55.41a.52.52,0,1,0,.27,1l1.3-.35-.46,1.26a.52.52,0,0,0,1,.36l.46-1.26.77,1.09a.52.52,0,1,0,.85-.59Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M50.57,13.6l-1.18-1.69,2-.53a.67.67,0,1,0-.35-1.3l-1.66.45L50,8.9A.68.68,0,0,0,49.55,8a.67.67,0,0,0-.86.4l-.59,1.63-1-1.42a.67.67,0,1,0-1.1.77l1.18,1.69-2,.53A.68.68,0,1,0,45.55,13l1.67-.45-.6,1.62A.69.69,0,0,0,47,15a.68.68,0,0,0,.86-.41L48.48,13l1,1.41a.68.68,0,0,0,.94.17A.66.66,0,0,0,50.57,13.6Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M59.93,31.91l-1.61-2.3L61,28.89a.92.92,0,1,0-.48-1.77l-2.26.61.8-2.21a.91.91,0,0,0-1.72-.62l-.8,2.2-1.35-1.92a.92.92,0,1,0-1.5,1.05l1.61,2.29-2.71.73A.9.9,0,0,0,52,30.37.92.92,0,0,0,53.1,31l2.26-.6-.8,2.2a.92.92,0,1,0,1.72.63L57.09,31,58.43,33a.92.92,0,0,0,1.28.22A.91.91,0,0,0,59.93,31.91Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M14.47,13.41l.92,1.3-1.55.42a.52.52,0,0,0,.27,1l1.3-.35L15,17.05a.52.52,0,1,0,1,.36l.46-1.26.77,1.1a.52.52,0,0,0,.85-.61l-.91-1.3,1.54-.42a.52.52,0,0,0,.37-.64.53.53,0,0,0-.64-.37l-1.29.35L17.54,13a.54.54,0,0,0-.32-.67.52.52,0,0,0-.67.31l-.46,1.26-.76-1.1a.53.53,0,0,0-.73-.12A.52.52,0,0,0,14.47,13.41Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M13.13,36.62l1.18,1.69-2,.53a.68.68,0,0,0,.35,1.31l1.67-.45-.59,1.62a.67.67,0,0,0,1.26.46l.59-1.62,1,1.41a.68.68,0,1,0,1.11-.77l-1.18-1.69,2-.53a.67.67,0,0,0-.35-1.3l-1.67.45.59-1.63a.67.67,0,0,0-.4-.86.68.68,0,0,0-.87.4l-.59,1.63-1-1.42a.67.67,0,0,0-.94-.16A.66.66,0,0,0,13.13,36.62Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M1.78,21.45l1.6,2.3-2.7.72a.92.92,0,1,0,.47,1.77l2.27-.61-.8,2.21a.91.91,0,1,0,1.72.62l.8-2.2,1.35,1.92a.91.91,0,0,0,1.27.23A.92.92,0,0,0,8,27.13L6.38,24.84l2.7-.73a.91.91,0,1,0-.47-1.76L6.34,23l.81-2.2a.93.93,0,0,0-.55-1.18.92.92,0,0,0-1.17.55l-.81,2.21L3.28,20.4A.92.92,0,0,0,2,20.18.91.91,0,0,0,1.78,21.45Z"></path></g></g></svg>
  </span>
  <h5>
  Climate Controlled
  </h5>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in IE now. It should work as you wanted. I removed box-sizing property and added height 100% to the h5 element.

```css
div{
  background:#fafafa;
  border-radius:3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;   
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:stretch;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
h5{
  flex-shrink:1;
  text-align:center;
  margin:5px auto;
  max-width:100%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  height : 100%;
}
span{
  display:block;
  display:flex;
  align-self:stretch;
}
svg{
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 61.71 62.15"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:currentColor;}</style></defs><title>myThermometer</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_2-2" data-name="Layer 2"><path class="cls-1" d="M34,45.55V36.82a2.92,2.92,0,1,0-5.84,0v8.73a6.68,6.68,0,1,0,5.84,0Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M38.11,43.46V7a7,7,0,1,0-14,0V43.46a10.67,10.67,0,1,0,14,0ZM31.1,60a8.48,8.48,0,0,1-4.83-15.45v-3.2h1v-1h-1V37.72h1v-1h-1V34.11h2.06a4.08,4.08,0,0,1,1.07-.76v-.22H26.27V30.51H29.4v-1H26.27V26.91H29.4v-1H26.27V23.3H29.4v-1H26.27V19.7H29.4v-1H26.27V16.1H29.4v-1H26.27V12.49H29.4v-1H26.27V8.89H29.4v-1H26.27V7a4.83,4.83,0,1,1,9.66,0v37.5A8.48,8.48,0,0,1,31.1,60Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M49.34,44.75l-.91-1.31L50,43a.52.52,0,0,0,.37-.64A.53.53,0,0,0,49.7,42l-1.29.35.46-1.26a.53.53,0,0,0-.32-.67.52.52,0,0,0-.67.32L47.43,42l-.77-1.09a.52.52,0,0,0-.86.59l.92,1.32-1.55.41a.52.52,0,1,0,.27,1l1.3-.35-.46,1.26a.52.52,0,0,0,1,.36l.46-1.26.77,1.09a.52.52,0,1,0,.85-.59Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M50.57,13.6l-1.18-1.69,2-.53a.67.67,0,1,0-.35-1.3l-1.66.45L50,8.9A.68.68,0,0,0,49.55,8a.67.67,0,0,0-.86.4l-.59,1.63-1-1.42a.67.67,0,1,0-1.1.77l1.18,1.69-2,.53A.68.68,0,1,0,45.55,13l1.67-.45-.6,1.62A.69.69,0,0,0,47,15a.68.68,0,0,0,.86-.41L48.48,13l1,1.41a.68.68,0,0,0,.94.17A.66.66,0,0,0,50.57,13.6Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M59.93,31.91l-1.61-2.3L61,28.89a.92.92,0,1,0-.48-1.77l-2.26.61.8-2.21a.91.91,0,0,0-1.72-.62l-.8,2.2-1.35-1.92a.92.92,0,1,0-1.5,1.05l1.61,2.29-2.71.73A.9.9,0,0,0,52,30.37.92.92,0,0,0,53.1,31l2.26-.6-.8,2.2a.92.92,0,1,0,1.72.63L57.09,31,58.43,33a.92.92,0,0,0,1.28.22A.91.91,0,0,0,59.93,31.91Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M14.47,13.41l.92,1.3-1.55.42a.52.52,0,0,0,.27,1l1.3-.35L15,17.05a.52.52,0,1,0,1,.36l.46-1.26.77,1.1a.52.52,0,0,0,.85-.61l-.91-1.3,1.54-.42a.52.52,0,0,0,.37-.64.53.53,0,0,0-.64-.37l-1.29.35L17.54,13a.54.54,0,0,0-.32-.67.52.52,0,0,0-.67.31l-.46,1.26-.76-1.1a.53.53,0,0,0-.73-.12A.52.52,0,0,0,14.47,13.41Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M13.13,36.62l1.18,1.69-2,.53a.68.68,0,0,0,.35,1.31l1.67-.45-.59,1.62a.67.67,0,0,0,1.26.46l.59-1.62,1,1.41a.68.68,0,1,0,1.11-.77l-1.18-1.69,2-.53a.67.67,0,0,0-.35-1.3l-1.67.45.59-1.63a.67.67,0,0,0-.4-.86.68.68,0,0,0-.87.4l-.59,1.63-1-1.42a.67.67,0,0,0-.94-.16A.66.66,0,0,0,13.13,36.62Z"></path><path class="cls-1" d="M1.78,21.45l1.6,2.3-2.7.72a.92.92,0,1,0,.47,1.77l2.27-.61-.8,2.21a.91.91,0,1,0,1.72.62l.8-2.2,1.35,1.92a.91.91,0,0,0,1.27.23A.92.92,0,0,0,8,27.13L6.38,24.84l2.7-.73a.91.91,0,1,0-.47-1.76L6.34,23l.81-2.2a.93.93,0,0,0-.55-1.18.92.92,0,0,0-1.17.55l-.81,2.21L3.28,20.4A.92.92,0,0,0,2,20.18.91.91,0,0,0,1.78,21.45Z"></path></g></g></svg>
  </span>
  <h5>
  Climate Controlled
  </h5>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Nandita, it is typically helpful for askers if you specify what you changed (and why) when presenting them with a code block that you say should work.

Comment: I updated the answer already, stating what I changed in their code. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I will keep this trick in mind. ^_^

Comment: @Nandita interesting, it's not actually respecting the content's height, it's just reserving more space for the h5 (test by removing some of the text to make it one line or adding enough to make it 3 lines). Do you know what the height 100% is actually doing in this context? Because it's not intuitive for me.

Comment: In IE flex items have trouble taking widths and height. Its preferable to set them so that it doesnt break in IE. I gave it 100% height so that it could take entire height needed for its content to fit. I am not sure though if this is the exact reason. But this fix has almost always worked for me with flex